# changing base url displayed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

here is my setup, I'm using 1 server to accept connections externally then redirects to one of my two websites, i am currently trying out reverse proxy, when i try to access www.example1.com i can successfully load the site, but when i go to my pages, my url displays x.x.x.1/page,what i want is www.example1.com/page I have been reading .htaccess notes also, but have not yet tried any of it, I need suggestions on how to solve this

Additional: my 2 websites are on different servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone experience a setup similar to mine, here is what i did

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "\x.x.x.x\var\www\example1"
ServerName www.example1.com
ServerAlias example1.com

<Proxy *>
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location / >
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "http://x.x.x.x/"
ProxyPassReverse "http://x.x.x.x/"
</Location>


</VirtualHost>
```